# Plesk 11 assign another plesk user (reseller or customer) to subscription

Tags: dns, plesk, assign, subscriptions

Is it possible in Plesk 11 to assign multiple plesk users (resellers, customers) to a single subscription? What i need is that multiple people (employees) can work on a single website with their own plesk account.

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Thanks!

Steffen

Answer (score 0):

There is possible to create additional(Auxiliary) users for subscription and this users will have access to plesk panel.

Check the docs at http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP11/11.0/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-customer-guide/69331.htm

But this users are not resellers or customers, it's subscription level users, they may have own roles and permissions and may have access to several subscriptions or only one subscription.